# Seconds to Human Readable Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, recursion, time

I saw a question online which required a program to convert numeric seconds into seconds, minutes, hours, days, years and i was able to come up with this function below

```
var arrTime = [];
function formatD(seconds){
    if(seconds > 0){
        if(seconds >= 1 && seconds <= 59){
            arrTime.push(seconds === 1 ? "1 second" : seconds + " seconds");
            return arrTime;
        }else
        if(seconds >= 60 && seconds <= 3599){
            arrTime.push(seconds === 60 ? "1 minute" : Math.floor(seconds/60) + " minutes");
            formatD(seconds - (Math.floor(seconds/60) * 60));
        }else
        if(seconds >= 3600 && seconds <= 86399){
            arrTime.push(seconds === 3600 ? "1 hour" : Math.floor(seconds/3600) + " hours");   
            formatD(seconds - (Math.floor(seconds/3600) * 3600))    
        }else
        if(seconds >= 86400 && seconds <= 31535999){
            arrTime.push(seconds === 86400 ? "1 day" : Math.floor(seconds/86400) + " hours");   
            formatD(seconds - (Math.floor(seconds/86400) * 86400))      
        }else{
            arrTime.push(seconds === 31536000 ? "1 year" : Math.floor(seconds/31536000) + " years");   
            formatD(seconds - (Math.floor(seconds/31536000) * 31536000))            
        }
    }
}
```

I have studied my code and with my basic recursion knowledge, i thought this would return an array including the result, for example if i entered

```
formatD(63)
```

i expected to see:

```
["1 minute", "3 seconds"]
```

But i keep getting no return value..any fix or something am doing wrong here?

Comment: Because you aren't returning anything except in the first if block.

Comment: just realized that @PatrickEvans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check your `arrTime` array.

And also return `arrTime` from the method that you wrote.

That should contain the time.

```js
var arrTime = new Array();
function formatD(seconds){
    if(seconds > 0){
        if(seconds >= 1 && seconds <= 59){
            arrTime.push(seconds === 1 ? "1 second" : seconds + " seconds");
            return arrTime;
        }else if(seconds >= 60 && seconds <= 3599){
            arrTime.push(seconds === 60 ? "1 minute" : Math.floor(seconds/60) + " minutes");
            formatD(seconds - (Math.floor(seconds/60) * 60));
        }else if(seconds >= 3600 && seconds <= 86399){
            arrTime.push(seconds === 3600 ? "1 hour" : Math.floor(seconds/3600) + " hours");   
            formatD(seconds - (Math.floor(seconds/3600) * 3600))    
        }else if(seconds >= 86400 && seconds <= 31535999){
            arrTime.push(seconds === 86400 ? "1 day" : Math.floor(seconds/86400) + " hours");   
            formatD(seconds - (Math.floor(seconds/86400) * 86400))      
        }else{
            arrTime.push(seconds === 31536000 ? "1 year" : Math.floor(seconds/31536000) + " years");   
            formatD(seconds - (Math.floor(seconds/31536000) * 31536000))            
        }
    }

   return arrTime;
}
console.log(formatD(65));
console.log(arrTime);
```

Comment: Works but i still have to suffer the global variable appending on the new values everytime i call the function :(

Comment: Put the `arrTime` in another method and call your method from there

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with two arrays for unit and corresponding value of seconds.

For getting plural words, you could use an object with words for one unit and other counts.

```js
function formatD(seconds) {
    function getPlural(number, word) {
        return number === 1 && word.one || word.other;
    }

    var words = {
            year: { one: 'year', other: 'years' },
            day: { one: 'day', other: 'days' },
            hour: { one: 'hour', other: 'hours' },
            minute: { one: 'minute', other: 'minutes' },
            second: { one: 'second', other: 'seconds' }
        },
        units = ['year', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second'],
        values = [365 * 24 * 60 * 60, 24 * 60 * 60, 60 * 60, 60, 1],
        result = [];

    units.reduce(function (s, u, i) {
        var temp = Math.floor(s / values[i]);
        if (temp) {
            result.push(temp + ' ' + getPlural(temp, words[u]));
        }
        return s % values[i];
    }, seconds);
    return result.join(' ');
}

console.log(formatD(63));
console.log(formatD(3600));
console.log(formatD(31536000));
console.log(formatD(31626102));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var n = 10000;
var hourre = n%3600;
n = n-hourre;
var hours = n;
n = hourre;
var minutesre = n%60;
var minutes = n - minutesre;
seconds = n- minutes;
n = n - seconds
alert( "hours:"+hours/3600+"minutes:"+minutes/60+"seconds:"+seconds);
```

I think this is right... % gets the remainder of a division.